# Make border of empty element disappear / Empty rule not working

Tags: html, css

I have build some "tags" that are above the title of my html construct in a line. The problem is they are not necessarily all filled with text. If one of these elements is empty it leaves the border "concentrated" on a "point". I tried it with the empty rule but its not working . I applied it to every element class in my code but not just "tags".

```css
.tags:empty{
    display:none;
    height: 0px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="tags"> <span class="icons2"> <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p> </span><span class="icons2"> <p class="leitung">{{leitung}}</p> </span><span class="icons2"> <p class="tag3">{{tag3}}</p> </span> <span class="icons3"> <p class="neu">{{neu}}</p> </span></div>
```

If you need more code just ask but I think this is sufficient.
Thank you.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: It is done with duda widget builder.

Comment: `:empty` also counts children so from your code `.tags` will never be empty. The only elements the `:empty` selector could work in your code are your `p`, as long as things like `{{jobArea}}` don't put any text in it

Comment: Yes Daniel, but I already applied it to them aswell ! Its not working Im afraid, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Is the `<p>`tag really empty then, white space will break the rule. It looks like handlebars? and an empty var will render a space

Comment: Provided code seems ok try to reproduce the problem visually in your code so that we can help, Or at-least a minimal code of problem

Comment: Yes it uses handlebars. I tried setting "content: none;" but it didnt help.